# The highest voted questions do not have research effort; this is a bad role model for new users

Tags: discussion, questions, upvotes, question-quality, old-questions

Many top-voted questions with hundreds of votes do not have any research effort:

- [How to manually send HTTP POST requests from Firefox or Chrome browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797534/how-to-manually-send-http-post-requests-from-firefox-or-chrome-browser)
- [How do I undo the most recent local commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-most-recent-local-commits-in-git)
- [How do you decode base64 data in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470546/how-do-you-decode-base64-data-in-python)
- [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage/506004#)
- [How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript/1789952#)
- [How do I force "git pull" to overwrite local files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/how-do-i-force-git-pull-to-overwrite-local-files/8888015#)
- [How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object/208106#)

These questions are of the form:

> how do I do something?

without any more clear research effort.

Because beginners see these upvoted questions, they use these as role models for their questions, which leads to **a flow of bad questions treating SO as a code writing service.**

What can we do about these upvoted, 0-research questions?

And more importantly, what can be done to encourage users **more (the first question dialog is not enough!)** to show research effort in their questions?

Comment: So you mean that new users don't know how time works and that something can evolve over time, like rules on Stack Overflow? I really hope those users aren't living in caves anymore.

Comment: One big problem with asking a question like that nowadays is that it's extremely likely to be a duplicate. I occasionally see well-received questions like that when a new framework or whatever is released.

Comment: Related: [Should Stack Exchange in general be awarding “A”s for Effort?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/210840/289905).

Comment: The second reference has 152 answers (incl. deleted answers)...

Answer (score 24):

There's nothing wrong with "how to" questions, as long as they are reasonably scoped and otherwise on-topic.

These questions are highly upvoted because they are *useful* to many people, which is the whole point of our Q&A model.

Stack Overflow *is* a code-writing service: you ask a specific question about a programming problem, and people will write answers containing code that solves the problem. What people mean when they say that it's not a code-writing service is that we won't write an entire application for you. This is why we do not allow questions that are excessively broad or unfocused. None of the questions you linked ask for an entire application to be written, nor are they excessively broad.

If you feel that those questions are bad because they show an insufficient level of research effort according to your own, inherently subjective standards, then you can indicate that by downvoting them. But there's nothing that we need to do about those questions as a site, because there's nothing wrong with those questions according to our policies.

Comment: and agin someone else that feels such question should be closed

Comment: And again many others don't!

Comment: @nbk I'm certainly sympathetic to your viewpoint. However, I don't think it's reasonable to *close* questions based on one's *feelings* even if one suspects that many users share that feeling. Note that in large part, the community decides what's ok, or not, so if you feel that questions should be closed for not showing research effort, then a proposal for that would be the right route. If there is indeed a sufficiently large section of the community which agrees, and a sound argument could be made in favor of it, then that would be the new policy. That is *not* the current policy however.

Comment: @cigien This here is a question and answer side, so users ask a question, almost always bad once. If you want to search for a good how to question look ip some of the higher points they show the way. Make research expülain what you have done so far and trued and ask about 1 single point. That the best someone can, do and everything else, need more focus. That is of course to black and white, i i exclude3 all greysnot from Roswell, that have also good questions, where small improvements and others that need even a bit more so go to the close review and go through the bottom of the barrel

Comment: I strongly disagree. When I joined SO a long time ago, it advertised itself as a user-moderated Q&A site — which IMO mean that if *we* (the community members) felt that the question asker hadn't done sufficient research or put enough effort into finding a solution themselves, we can say so and vote the close the question. Apparently that's changed (and I don't like it).

Comment: @martineau We've always had and still do have that power, through casting downvotes. However, what we don't have is the ability to throw out the opinions of others on those same judgements. When exceptions occur, A post here on meta can get moderators to intervene if there's enough interest in doing so.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the [message](https://stackoverflow.com/users/message/91592#91592) I got today from the Stack Overflow Moderation Team — at least the "Lack of research or problem-solving effort is not a reason to close or otherwise object to questions" part. It seems like they are throwing out *my* opinion.

Comment: they threw out a close vote for a reason that isn't a reason that we use to close questions.

Comment: @martineau What that message is trying to tell you is that you have been misusing your close votes to close questions for invalid reasons. While the application of the close reasons is somewhat subjective, it's not entirely subjective. There are some pretty clear-cut rules, and lack of research or problem-solving effort has never been a reason to close a question and still isn't now. If that means we're throwing out opinions that are invalid, well...

Comment: I'm still going to still downvote questions that show a lack of effort on the part of the asker making them essentially just a list of requirements. May also vote to close due to a lack of clarity or perhaps needing debugging information. If that's grounds for suspension, so be it.

Comment: Yes, @martineau, that is a downvote reason (see tooltip). It isn't a close reason. And if one of the close reasons applies, such as the question being unclear or not being a question, then you should definitely (also) vote to close. I don't believe anyone has tried to tell you otherwise. I believe you were linked to [this answer](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260909): "The only type of effort we require is the effort required to ask a clear, focused, non-duplicate question." Failure to expend certain types of effort is a reason to close. Failure to work hard enough to solve the problem isn't.

Answer (score 11):

### All of these are great questions

They describe a focused problem clearly and with no extra noise about how long they've spent researching it or whatever completely wrong attempt they made.  And *that's great, because it makes the question better*.

As I argued [over on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/364585/165261), **please stop trying to turn Stack Overflow into a debugging helpdesk**.  It's not, it's a question and answer site.  Debugging the nth NullPointerException isn't a good question.  It won't help anyone else.  All of these questions have helped countless people.

Ultimately, Stack Overflow *is* a code-writing service, because answering programming questions *tends to involve writing code*. Everyone telling people that it's not a code-writing service because they haven't put in enough effort to deserve help is doing the site a disservice.

Answer (score 7):

Thankfully, we still exist to some varying degree to provide guidance for new users who ask such questions on our site - in the form of downvotes and closures.

The older questions exist on this site in this form because:

- **They are old**.  Some of these examples are well over ten years old and Stack Overflow was a ***very different place*** back then.
- **They are still valuable**.  Those answers are some of the best on the site, and are referenced and indexed by every major search engine.

No, new users cannot use, "But *this* old question asked a question like I did, and *they* didn't get closed!  Why am I being unfairly targeted?" as a defense.

Comment: This answer seems to suggest that while asking "how-to" questions without showing research effort was acceptable before, those questions are no longer acceptable. If so, I have to disagree; "how-to" questions are harder to ask these days, because a *lot* of them have already been asked, but they're still perfectly valid. Nothing has changed in regard to "how-to" questions being acceptable. Curators seem to react more negatively to them than they used to, but the rules are still the same, right?

Comment: @cigien: You've got that backwards. Apparent asking "how-to" questions is now acceptable but wasn't before. I object especially to those that could have easily been resolved by RTFM or doing a little research, but the OP obviously hasn't bothered to do either — because it's easier to just post a question here and let others do the work for them.