# Please add "tutorials" back to the off-site close reason text

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, close-reasons

The old close reason text for the off-topic close reason of 'off-site resources' used to explicitly enumerate "tutorial" in the list of examples of what wasn't allowed:

[image: Old close vote window showing "tutorial" included in the recommendation request reason/option, with the word "tutorial" encircled in red]

Unfortunately, the new version does not have this word enumerated:

[image: Current dark mode close vote modal showing the recommendation request reason/option, with a caret and question mark drawn in the position of the enumerated items where the word "tutorial" is missing]

I would like to request we add the word "tutorial" back to that list of enumerated, top-level examples of things not allowed. There is plenty of horizontal space for it already, thanks to the long description under "Needs debugging details".

This is a rather small request, but is also one that doesn't require a developer to change.

Comment: This close reason is already abused for when someone asks for code examples. Having tutorial might give the impression that such questions are off-topic. I think "and more" currently covers tutorials.

Comment: "**or other off-site resource**" was the key. The close reason is for requesting off-site resources, it just so happens that the ones listed are off-site. Adding tutorials to the list without clarifying off-site would, as Dharman expressed, actually make it cover on-site tutorials as well if written that way. Add "tutorials" or don't, but "or other off-site resources" is what is missing.

Comment: Yep. off-site resource is what transforms the question into a request for poorly received link-only answers. If someone wants to write up a good tutorial and post it as an answer, good on them. Tricky part is keeping it focussed; usually a tutorial will be covering multiple issues.

Comment: Also yet again (this has been pointed out multiple times), it needs to say __or__ other off-site resources not _and_ other off-site resources. I have never seen a question asking for books _and_ tools _and_ software libraries _and_ more. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410999/close-reason-seeking-recommendations-text-is-still-wrong

Comment: @Dharman I haven't seen people misusing the close reason as you mention. However, asking for examples of code sounds like it's off-topic. Do you have a specific example to help clarify?

Comment: @Lundin I agree, "or" would be better than "and". If this gets a [tag:status-review] tag, I'm sure the CM reviewing it can make that change alongside the other(s).

Comment: @user4581301 True, it's the scope that makes the difference; you could argue that any answer is a 'tutorial', after a fashion.

Comment: @TylerH I've pointed it out in multiple times the past and one of the times I even got a status-complete tag (can't find the post...). Shows what those tags are worth.

Comment: @Lundin Are you referring to this one? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410999/close-reason-seeking-recommendations-text-is-still-wrong I can't find any relevant questions by you with the [meta-tag:status-completed] tag.

Comment: @Lundin The only one with [tag:status-completed] is this one: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412531/closing-as-lacking-debugging-details-gives-an-unhelpful-message-to-the-poster

Comment: @TylerH I think it was an answer which got a tag appended to it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## What's missing is *or other off-site resources.*

There's no indication on the current close reason for what this reason is *actually* meant for, it doesn't specify off-site resources, it just mentioned a few resources that happen to be off-site.

I'm not against *also* adding tutorials to the list, but I don't think that's really going to change anything. If it's a request for an off-site resource, it's off topic, regardless of how many examples of off-site resources are provided.

Comment: Actually that text wasn't very helpful, because asking where to find _on-site_ resources isn't on topic either. Turns out asking where to find _any_ resource is off-topic.

Comment: Sure, "or other off-site resources" would achieve about the same thing, I think. I'm fine with that change instead of just adding "tutorials".

Comment: I agree have used this before as well for people just asking for someone to paraphrase the documentation to them.

Answer (score 15):

In my opinion this should be phrased as:

> **Seeking recommendations for which learning materials, tools, or libraries to use, or where to find them.**

Notably, in the English language the word ***or*** has a significantly different meaning than the word ***and***.

*Learning materials* include:

- Books
- Tutorials (written or videos)
- The friendly manual
- The friendly `man` and results spawned from it
- Official or unofficial documentation (like blogs)
- Articles and application notes

*Libraries* means software libraries, since this is a software site. "Software" is redundant. In the highly unlikely event someone is asking where to find an actual library building, then it is blatantly off-topic too, so there's no need to make a distinction.

Answer (score 3):

#### Requests for (focused<sup>1</sup>) tutorials are on-topic.
Requests for *links* to tutorials are off-topic.

Enough people are confused by this close reason already.  Let's not confuse people more by adding phrasing that could be misread to suggest that how-to questions (which are asking for, in essence, a small tutorial) are off-topic. It's already a common enough point of confusion.

See [Cody Gray's explanation of why Stack Overflow *is* a code-writing service](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408565/208273) or [my post on not turning Stack Overflow into a debugging helpdesk](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/364585/165261) for why these posts are valuable and closing them would be a mistake.

For this reason, I would rather the phrasing focus on recommendations for *links* being a problem, rather than tutorials.

---

<sup>1: Requests for long, unfocused tutorials have their own close reason: Needs more focus</sup>

Comment: This is basically a concurrence to [Kevin B's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/415889/208273), which I also agree with, though I'd perhaps favor phrasing that includes the word "links."

Comment: The term tutorial isn't helpful if some users give it a different meaning than others. Nowadays it refers to Internet learning resources of often very low quality, including Youtube and various infamous tutorial sites. Maybe it should say "requests for where to find learning material is off-topic".

Comment: Re: the footnote, there are a few different kinds of questions were multiple prescribed close reasons apply; I don't see that as an issue of concern.

Comment: @TylerH Agreed, that's why it's a footnote: this close reason isn't *supposed* to apply to them.  It's just a reminder that there's already a close reason for people asking for unfocused tutorials (who are not requesting links).

Comment: @RyanM Well, if someone is requesting you recommend an already-written tutorial (e.g. a blog post on how to do some thing in X language), then it _does_ apply.